# Jupyter Notebook scrollbar doesn't disappear?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda on Chrome browser. When I'm writing longer lines of code that require a scrollbar in the cell, I have problems with the scrollbar not disappearing. Sometimes the scrollbar appears when needed as I scroll, and correctly disappears after I'm done scrolling. But for some reason (seemingly randomly), the scrollbar will sometimes linger and never go away, even when I try clicking out of the cell, reentering the cell, scrolling and moving the cursor, etc.

This may seem like a small issue, but it actually becomes quite annoying because the scrollbar blocks my bottom line of code, so I need to add a line to the bottom of my cell to read the bottom line. But since the scrollbar is there, I have to very intricately click into the line, or manually move the cursor to the end of the row to add a line, or else it thinks I'm clicking the scrollbar, not the line of code itself. Very frustrating!

Here's a [screenshot of the lingering scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR6yP.png).

How do I get the scrollbar to disappear when no longer needed?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: This is a known issue with Chrome on macOS, nothing to do with Jupyter unfortunately. The same thing happens here on SO.

Comment: Yes that ticket totally solved my problem, thanks so much @darthbith ! For reference, it's a MacOS Chrome bug and the fix is permanently keeping all scrollbars on by going to System Preferences > General > Show Scroll Bars (choose Always).